# How to generate DocBlock comments in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, documentation, comments, doxygen, phpdoc

I'm working with legacy PHP code that has a lot of functions with one-line comments (// ...).

But for documentation generators like doxygen and phpDocumentor to document those functions to the fullest extent, the functions need to be in DocBlock format:

```
/**
  * Summary
  *
  * Description
  *
  * @param etc
*/
```

Does NetBeans provide a way to automatically generate a DocBlock comment given a method signature and / or a one-line comment preceding a function?

Answer (score 3):

Use /** to generate the DocBlock.

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking to customize this "/**" macro shortcut. It would be awesome if I could also find it in the tools.